# Android: Button below GridView does not call onClick

Tags: android, button, gridview, onclick

I have an `AppCompatActivity` which implements `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

My `.xml` layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.DocumentsActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_documents" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".activities.DocumentsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my `content_documents.xml` file consists of a LinearLayout containing a GridView and a Button at the bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".activities.DocumentsActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_documents"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_add_document"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:text="ADD DOCUMENT"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I'm setting an onClickListener to the Button like so:

```
Button addDocument = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add_document);
    addDocument.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Button", "Clicked");
        }
    });
```

but the onClick() method is never called.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but are You sure You have setup Logcat monitor correct? The filter is important for Log, just try to make a toast and see if it´s really not working...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes, I am sure it is set correctly. I have it on Verbose and this is set to be shown as an error, so it should be visible

Comment: ok, I´m just asking because I recognized in AS that also if set to verbose, and also if set a Tag, It could bet that nothing is shown. Additionaly, I disable "Show only selected Application" to show the full output....

Comment: and I can´t see any issue in Your code.....

Comment: I tried changing it to a Toast but it doesn't work either...

Comment: hmmpff....that´s very weird. There must be anywhere an issue in Your code, can You please post the complete Activity (if not too large)...

Comment: I found a workaround. Initially, my activity implemented NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener. Apparently, this listener was overriding the onItemSelectedListener from GridView, so I just removed the NavigationView and everything works now...I'll leave the question open just in case someone can help me solve it, but I'll leave it for the time being. Thanks a lot anyway @Opiatefuchs!!

Comment: ok, but that´s very strange..... :)